# Matplotlib having different x ticks that the index from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a `numpy` array but I want to change the x ticks value of the `plot`. I want to have negative index, from instance for an array of `size` 20, I want to have x ticks in range of `[-9,10]`

I tried this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 20

seq = np.full(size, 1)
for i in range(size//2, size):
    seq[i] = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(seq)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-size//2+1, size//2+1, 1))
plt.show()
```

But I have an unexpected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use plt.xticks() instead of ax.set_xticks()**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 20

seq = np.full(size, 1)
for i in range(size//2, size):
    seq[i] = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(seq)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
plt.xticks(labels=np.arange(-size//2+1, size//2+1, 1),
           ticks=range(size),
           rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoMmC.png)

Comment: I prefer used `ax.set_xticks()` but with your solution I see that I can use `ax.set_xticklabels`, so with `ax.set_xticks(range(size))` and `ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(-size//2+1, size//2+1, 1))`, it's work as excepted, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using `ax.plot(np.arange(-size//2+1, size//2+1, 1), seq)`  that plot the numpy array with the x ticks I wanted, the result:

[image]